# Spring Data JPA Testing

Tags: testing, spring-data-jpa

The JPA examples all seem to test with @SpringBootTest.  Is this best practice now, or is it possible to still perform Dao level testing without starting up the entire container?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `@DataJpaTest`. This will setup an application context where the JPA related beans are registered only (Repositories, TransactionManager etc.). So if you want to focus on Dao level testing (for example with an in-memory-database) this will be the proper choice.